# combobox wxpython program doesn't have time to make a choice

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm writing a program so I can send SMS via email and using wxpython.  Using Combobox to select which carrier the phone number is attached to.  However, the program continues with everything else before I have a chance to select a carrier.  Is there a way to make this halt until I make a choice?  Still learning how to copy/paste in here so forgive any indentation errors, it's all correct in my code.  Thanks everyone! :)

```
  if password.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
      pwd =password.GetValue()
      phone_number = wx.TextEntryDialog(self,"Phone Number", "Phone Number", "")
      if phone_number.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        number = phone_number.GetValue()
        self.carrier = wx.ComboBox(self, -1, pos=(10, 50), choices=carriers, style=wx.CB_READONLY)
        self.carrier.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.onCombo)
        if self.carrier.ShowModal() == wx.EVT_COMBOBOX:
           message = wx.TextEntryDialog(self,"Your Message", "Your Message", "")
           if message.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:

              msg = message.GetValue()
              smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
              smtpserver.ehlo()
              smtpserver.starttls()
              smtpserver.ehlo
              smtpserver.login(username, pwd)
              header = 'To:' + email + '\n' + 'From: ' + username + '\n' + 'Subject:testing \n'
              print header
              msg1 = header + msg
              smtpserver.sendmail(username, email, msg1)
              smtpserver.close()

 def onCombo(self, event):


    self.selection = self.carrier.GetValue()
    print self.selection
    print self.number
    self.email = number + selection
    print email
    return self.email
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right away I can tell you that `self.carrier` is of type `wx.ComboBox` and does not have a `ShowModal()` method. And if it did it wouldn't return `wx.EVT_COMBOBOX`. The `ShowModal()` method returns the ID of the button that was clicked. `wx.EVT_COMBOBOX` is an event, not an ID and thus would not be returned.

Only `wx.Dialog`s use `ShowModal()`. It looks like the dialog you want is a `wx.SingleChoiceDialog` (You can find a tutorial [here](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/07/10/the-dialogs-of-wxpython-part-2-of-2/) but you'll need to scroll about 7/8 of the way down. Or just hit `ctrl+f` and search for "singlechoice"). This will show a list and prompt users to make a single selection.

Alternatively, you could create your own custom dialog (tutorials [here](http://wiki.wxpython.org/AnotherTutorial/#Custom_dialogs) and [here](http://zetcode.com/wxpython/dialogs/)) that contain all the information you need in a single convenient dialog (instead of three separate ones).

I wrote **rough** draft that you can find below. Just remember that I haven't tested it so there may be errors, but it should give you an idea of what you need to do. Also, you should probably place the objects in a sizer and organize the layout the way you want it.

```
class MyTxtMsgDialog (wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent=parent, title="My Txt Message Dialog")

        self.number = wx.TextCtrl(self)
        self.carrier = wx.ComboBox(self, -1, pos=(10, 50), choices=carriers, style=wx.CB_READONLY)
        self.message = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TC_MULTILINE) #means this TextCtrl will be multiple lines, not just one
        self.okButton = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_OK, "OK")
        #Setting the ID to wx.ID_OK is important. Any of the wx.ID_* variables work natively with ShowModal()
        #but if you created your own ID using the wx.NewId() method then you will need to manually call
        #"self.EndModal(<your ID>)" when your button is clicked.
```

You'd then call it using:

```
txtMsgDialog = MyTxtMsgDialog(self)
if txtMsgDialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK: #check to see if OK was pressed
    #save the values
    self.number = txtMsgDialog.number.GetValue()
    self.carrier = txtMsgDialog.carrier.GetGetValue()
    self.message = txtMsgDialog.message.GetValue()

    txtMsgDialog.Destroy() #close the dialog
```

<s>One final note: as you can see in my example, it's a good idea to call the `Destroy()` method on all of your dialogs when you're done with them. This will close them and free the resources. Be careful though because after you call this method any variables you didn't already save will be gone.</s>
I see the reason you aren't calling `Destroy()` is because of an answer to a question you asked previously. It's mostly a style issue but I think that other commenter was wrong and you should destory your dialogs when you are done with them. It closes the dialog, frees up your resources, and it's the way all the tutorials are written.

Comment: Awesome! Got it working and was able to finish my program! Much thanks for the great response. :)